# How to read / identify cylindrical ceramic capacitors

Tags: capacitor

as this is my first post I'm not quite sure as to how I should format this question but here goes. I am trying to sort a set of ceramic capacitors and I have come upon a few that I can't identify. When I look up the text on their sides (all the same) nothing if relevance comes up. I think they are 1nF, but I'm not sure. Any help with how to read these would be much appreciated. The tet says "MKT .01 63/K," Images below.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Doesn't look like ceramic.  Looks like film of some kind.  I'd read .01 as 10nF.  I'll see if I can find something.

Comment: @JRE Any success?

Comment: is that from Dearborn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MKT means it is a metallized polyester film capacitor. 0.01 should mean 10nF, 63 means max AC voltage and K means 10% tolerance. The manufacturer logo is quite blurry, but regardless of that these should be identical between manufacturers.

Answer (score 2):

.01 means .01 uF, MKT means metallized polyester, 63 means 63 volts, K means 10% tolerance
I hope I got that all right.